# MySQL syntax error in stored procedure inserting records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

I am trying to create this stored procedure in MySQL. However, MySQL does not accept this procedure and displays that there is a syntax error. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? By the way, I am new to writing stored procedures.

```
  DELIMITER $$
   CREATE definer=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 'login_insert'
   ( IN uname     VARCHAR(20),
     IN paword    VARCHAR(20),
     OUT result    INT)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO db1.login_tab
          (           username,
                      pword,
           )
           VALUES
          (
                      uname,
                      paword,
           )
          IF @@ERROR = 0 
            SET @result = 0 
          ELSE SET @result = 5 
          RETURN @result 
   END$$ 
    DELIMITER ;
```

Changing it to the following as per below suggestion is not helping either. I have removed the return statement completely

```
         DELIMITER $$
              CREATE definer=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 'login_insert'
                     ( IN uname     VARCHAR(20),
                      IN paword    VARCHAR(20),
                       OUT result    INT)
             BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO db1.login_tab
                            (           username,
                                         pword
                             )
                             VALUES
                             (
                                uname,
                                paword
                              )
                   END$$ 
                  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: a PROCEDURE does not return a value (a FUNCTION should `RETURN` a value),  `@result` is a user-defined variable, entirely separate from procedure argument named `result`, the `IF` statement seems to be missing `THEN` keyword, the SQL statements in the procedure are missing statement terminator semicolon, there's spurious commas following pword and paword in the INSERT syntax.   This question is not going to be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Typically, MySQL will return an error message when a statement fails to execute, (in this case,  a CREATE PROCEDURE statement... that gives us a clue as to what MySQL thinks is wrong...) absent that we observe the INSERT statement should end with a semicolon, as a statement terminator.  (The reason for the rigmarole changing the delimiter to two dollar signs is that so that a semicolon inside the procedure isn't seen as prematurely terminating the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.)